# Unable to inject restangular into AngularJS App

Tags: rest, angularjs, dependency-injection

I have this angular app and controller modules defined as follows:

```
var myTasks = angular.module('myTasks', [
                                          'ngRoute',
                                          'myTasksControllers'
                                        ]);
var myTasksControllers = angular.module('myTasksControllers',[]);
```

I also have:

```
    <script src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/lodash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/restangular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

And I am trying to inject `rectangular` into my controller like so:

```
myTasksControllers.controller('ProjectsController', ['$scope','rectangular',
  function ($scope, Rectangular) {
    ...
    ...
  }
]);
```

But it keeps telling module not defined or something. To be precise:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.3/$injector/unpr?p0=rectangularProvider%20%3C-%20rectangular
    at Error (<anonymous>)
```

Rectangular: https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#how-do-i-add-this-to-my-project

Comment: Well, "re*c*tangular" is not the same as "re*s*tangular".

Comment: Omg. Im sorry I didnt notice that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to inject `restangular` module into your `myTasks` module first. Like this:

```
var myTasks = angular.module('myTasks', [
                                      'restangular',
                                      'ngRoute',
                                      'myTasksControllers'
                                    ]);
```

Than, you have to inject `Restangular` into your controller:

```
myTasksControllers.controller('ProjectsController', ['$scope','Restangular',
  function ($scope, Restangular) {
    ...
    ...
  }
]);
```

P.S.: Note that you have spelled it "rectangular" in your question :)

Comment: Thank you!! it worked. Thanks a lot. ANd sorry for the typo. :)

Comment: I had a similar issue and the I solved it by including a reference to lodash in my index.html file.

Comment: @AdamLabi Yes, because Lodash is a dependency of Restangular :)